# Post Json String get NULL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have converted all the entries of a form into an object and then fill it using the object to fill an array:

```
var jsonObj = [];
var formData = new FormData();
$('[name="'+form+'"] *').not(':input[type=file], :input[type=button], :input[type=submit], :input[type=reset], [name="input_search"]').filter(':input').each(function(obj, v) {
    var iObj        = {}
    var input       = $(this);
    var inputname   = input.attr("name");
    var val         = input.val();
    var inputval    = val;
    iObj[inputname] = inputval;
    jsonObj.push(iObj);
});
```

Later i try to convert the Final array into a Json String with this:

```
jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
```

and i get this String:

```
[{"s-file[]":"Prueba 3"},{"text_file[]":"ORT0000133.pdf"},{"idform":"f-gen-desk"},{"idprocess":"p-save"}]
```

i send this to PHP Server With this, becouse i send other Element type File with `formData.append` method:

```
formData.append('jsonData', jsonData);
var url = 'index.php';
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: formdata,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    },
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

In PHP server Side i try to get this string:

```
echo var_dump($_POST['jsonData']);
```

and i get this string:

```
string(169) "[{"s-file[]":"Prueba 3"},{"text_file[]":"ORT0000133.pdf"},{"idform":"f-gen-desk"},{"idprocess":"p-save"}]"
```

when i try to conver this to and Array with this:

Test 1:

```
echo '<pre>';
echo var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

ouput:

```
array(1) {
  ["jsonData"]=>
  string(169) "[{"s-file[]":"Prueba 3"},{"text_file[]":"ORT0000133.pdf"},{"idform":"f-gen-desk"},{"idprocess":"p-save"}]"
}
```

Test 2:

```
echo '<pre>';
$jsonData=$_POST['jsonData'];
$Data=json_decode($jsonData);
echo var_dump($Data);
echo '</pre>';
```

ouput: I get `NULL`.

I do not understand what I do wrong

**Last Update:**

i run this test:

```
echo '<pre>';
$jsonData   = '|'.$_POST['jsonData'].'|';
$json       = '|'.'[{"s-file[]":"Prueba 3"},{"text_file[]":"casa.jpg"},{"idform":"f-gen-desk"},{"idprocess":"p-save"}]'.'|';
echo $Line = mb_strlen(mb_strcut($jsonData, 0, strspn($jsonData ^ $json, "\0")));
echo '<br>';
echo $jsonData[$Line];
echo '<br>';
echo $json[$Line];
echo '<br>';
echo '</pre>';
```

**Output**

```
3
&
"
```

**I can determine that the chain is corrupt, but I can not know why or how or how to fix it.**

Comment: what?? sorry, it's really hard to understand 1st what you wanna do 2nd what the problem is.

Comment: @Jeff Updated and Corrected my question.

Comment: 1. Look at and/or post the JSON so we can too. 2. [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php

Comment: i have added this string

Comment: WFM: https://3v4l.org/4e6G4

Comment: mmm my PHP server Side return NULL :(

Comment: Change `var_dump($_POST['Data'])` to `var_dump($Data)`.

Comment: i have updated it and get the some....

Comment: What does `echo json_last_error();` show?

Comment: i get this on echo: 4

Comment: it could be that this in the string is breaking it: `s-file[]` specifically: `[]` then how to send the data about the selected files in the form. i use php 7.1

Comment: @Barmar last Update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be related to the use of:

```
$_GET  = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9854121/963200

need work around it to solve and use after read the data from `POST` and `GET`

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way to send json is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: jsonData, // stringified JSON
    contentType: 'application/json',
   // processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    //cache: false, POST won't cache
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    },
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

And receive in php

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')[,boolean to force array]);
```

---

Easiest way to send data in general is to use `serialize()` on form and send as default content type and receive various fields as `$_POST[inputName]`